# outlook AppointmentItem LastModificationTime doesn't update

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, appointment, zimbra

I'm currently working with Outlook 2013/2016.
My Outlook account is linked to a Zimbra server (I try it with an ActiveSync server but with the same result).

Here are my steps :

1. When I create an appointment, the LastModificationTime property take the current dateTime value => OK
2. On the Zimbra server the new appointment appear => OK
3. When I move my appointment in Outlook, the LastModificationTime property take the event dateTime value => OK
4. On the Zimbra server the appointment have been updated with the new date => OK
5. When I move my appointment in Zimbra, the appointment move on Outlook => Ok.
   But when I'm reading the LastModificationTime property, it's doesn't change with the new value (last event or last synchronisation between Outlook and Zimbra).

For my application (Outlook AddIn) I use this property, so I need it to be updated. I try to use the update/create event on appointment to change the LastModificationTime but it's not good for the moment.

Do you have any idea or suggestion ? (use other property perhaps).

Thks

Comment: Does PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME property get updated with your look at the appointment with OutlookSpy (click IMessage)?

Comment: I just install it. And I confirm, when I select my appointment and then click en Item (Outlook Object Model), the property LastModificationTime doesn't change (after an update on the server). Where can I find the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME ?

Comment: Did you look at the appointment with OutlookSpy (click IMessage)? http://www.dimastr.com/outspy

Comment: Hello, yes I use the iMessage to get the informations.
In GetProps tab I save to file the datas. I update my appointment on the server, and reopen iMessage and save datas in another file.
I merge the two files, and only the AppointmentStartWhole and AppointmentEndWhole change.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm you, the value doesn't change :

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg156895%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396


Outlook.PropertyAccessor propAcc = itemOutlook.PropertyAccessor;
DateTime outStrDT = propAcc.GetProperty(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30080040");
```